# Extract Values from Lattice Histogram

Tags: r, lattice

I have created an equal area histogram using `histogram()` in the Lattice, however, I can't seem to find a way to extract the values in the 20 equal are sized bins. Any suggestions? I've also looked into using ggplot2, but I can't create equal area sized bins while having the capability of extracting the data using `ggplot_build`. Here's an example:

```
library(lattice)

cell <- 1:20

psi <- rnorm(1:20)

histogram(df$psi,
          freq = TRUE,
          equal.width = FALSE,
          breaks = NULL,
          nint = 20)
```

[image: Equal Area Histogram]

As you can see in the figure, an equal area histogram is generated, but now I'd like to know which values from `df$psi` are within each bin of the histogram. I've tried assigning the plot to a new variable `dfhist <- hist()` and then inspecting the new variable `dfhist$` yet it doesn't appear as though the results for each bin are stored anywhere. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are in the `panel.args[[1]]$x` of your plot called for example `p` like this:

```r
library(lattice)
cell <- 1:20
psi <- rnorm(1:20)
df <- data.frame(cell = cell,
                 psi = psi)

p <- lattice::histogram(df$psi,
          freq = TRUE,
          equal.width = FALSE,
          breaks = NULL,
          nint = 20)

p$panel.args[[1]]$x
#>  [1]  0.57126799  0.52931270  1.09610583  0.40210029 -0.51261307 -1.47656641
#>  [7] -1.15286025 -1.62896968 -0.41758147  0.46671218  2.54717967 -1.08131256
#> [13] -0.03050443 -0.25765653  1.60843681  1.43767274  1.72095174 -0.21045430
#> [19]  0.04033122 -0.38105514
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>